# relative file path to fonts in css file

Tags: html, css

I have a stylesheet that is referenced in the header:

```
<link href="./css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

All of the css works in it except this specific code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src: url('fonts/icomoon.eot?hsw0h3');
    src: url('fonts/icomoon.eot?hsw0h3#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?hsw0h3') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.woff?hsw0h3') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.svg?hsw0h3#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

When I put the above **@font-face** CSS in the page above where the icons are being shown it works but when I put it in the CSS file it stops working. I finally found out that this was likely due to the file path not being correct.

Here is the file structure:

[image]

Looking at this article (https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/) it looks like I should either use:

```
url('/fonts/icomoon.ttf?hsw0h3')
url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf?hsw0h3')
```

to go back to the root and then into the fonts folder. But the icon still is not rendering from the CSS file.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Either way should work. How are you actually using your font-face declaration? Does the developer console show any errors?

Comment: Why you have some additional symbols after file extension?

Comment: @Andrew I am using https://icomoon.io/app/ to generate the font, it generates this css for me. Again, this code works fine in style tags on the actual HTML page.

Comment: @Teison T. Yes, Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 56, accepted):

URLs in CSS files are *relative to the CSS file*.

`url('fonts/icomoon.eot?hsw0h3');` means `http://example.com/css/fonts/icomoon.eot?hsw0h3`, but your screenshot of your directory structure shows you need `http://example.com/fonts/icomoon.eot?hsw0h3`.

Add `../` or `/`

Comment: If that css-file is loaded by the client, and not read and served in-line by some server-side library, naturally.

Comment: @HerbertVan-Vliet — If that hypothetical server-side library is inlining CSS without adjusting relative URLs then it is broken.

Answer (score 0):

`../` need to be added before the path to move up one folder in hierarchy (`../../path`) to move two folders up in hierarchy

Answer (score -2):

Consider describing the font sources individually without any **version specification** (I guess) like,

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src: url('fonts/icomoon.eot');
    src: url('fonts/icomoon.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
    src: url('fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype');
    src: url('fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff');
    src: url('fonts/icomoon.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Alternatively, you may also remove the `format` specification and let the browser to determine automatically, if problem still persists.