# css automatically adds slash on render

Tags: css

I've added **CSS** to the page

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "feather";
  src:url("fonts/feather-webfont.eot");
  src:url("fonts/feather-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
      url("fonts/feather-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
      url("fonts/feather-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
      url("fonts/feather-webfont.svg#feather") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
```

But, when render **CSS**. It automatically adds slash so **CSS** not working

[image: CSS In DevTools]

How can I remove slash when rendering **CSS**?
Thank you!

Comment: What are you using to produce the output css? is there any configuration? what is serving your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "feather";
  src:url("/assets/admin/vendors/feather/fonts/feather-webfont.eot");
  src:url("/assets/admin/vendors/feather/fonts/feather-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("/assets/admin/vendors/feather/fonts/feather-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
    url("/assets/admin/vendors/feather/fonts/feather-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("/assets/admin/vendors/feather/fonts/feather-webfont.svg#feather") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

i added assets path and it works

Answer (score -2):

Try change the path with "../fonts/" or "./fonts/" instead of "fonts/" if possible.

Comment: thanks but the render is still the same

Comment: Please refer to this hope it helps,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581901/relative-file-path-to-fonts-in-css-file